# Get all opened streams by the application

Tags: c#

I am using an external DLL that has the following functions: void OpenToolbarStream() and void CloseToolbarStream(). There is no documentation for this dll and neither google can help with it. Is there I way to find all the currently opened streams by the current application?

Comment: Write wrappers around these functions and track their calls yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: What do I get by tracking the calls? I know when they are called. I want to read the content of stream but I don't know how to access the stream.

Comment: I may be misreading your question. Do you mean you don't know how to use the result of `OpenToolbarStream`? How would knowing what streams are currently open help in that case?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: OpenToolbarStream() returns void and has no input parameters. So I don't know how to access the result. If I knew which streams are open right know then I could find the stream opened by OpenToolbarStream() because I know what the stream should contain so by searching for some keywords in the stream content I can find the right stream.

Comment: Either there is only one stream ever, or `OpenToolbarStream` has an output parameter that receives the stream on exit, or there is another function to get the toolbar stream(s) after opening them. Do you have code of the application you're in, possibly decompiled? Because it'll be hard to figure out how the functions are used otherwise. In particular, if you don't even know what a toolbar stream *is*, you have no way of getting at them. They're probably not `FILE` kernel objects. It's not like the runtime will keep a handy list for you.